# GNU/Linux, Fedora 17, login message

Tags: linux, login

Is there a program that displays the login message formatted like this:

```
Last login: Wed Oct 24 16:40:33 2012
```

Or do I have to write my own program/script?
I was wondering if there is a command the Linux kernel (or whoever) runs to do that.

Comment: Check `# man last` (shows details of last logged in users).

`# echo last -n 2  root >> /etc/profile` would show last 2 logged-in session for user 'root'. Is it that you was looking for?

Comment: No. I would like it to be in the format mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote some code to do it for me:

```
LINE=`lastlog -u $USER | head -n2 | tail -n1`;
WORDS=`echo "$LINE" | wc -w`;
if [ "x$WORDS" = "x9" ]; then
  echo "$LINE" | awk '{ printf "Last login: %s %s  %s %s %s from %s\n", $4, $5, $6, $7, $9, $3 }';
else
  echo "Unsupported case.";
fi;
```

It doesn't work for non-remote logins, but I am running the code on a headless server, so 99.9% of the logins will be remote logins; the other 0.1% will be when I "attach a head" to fix `ssh` issues or similar.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel does not track login information. You can configure PAM (`/etc/pam.d`) to call the `pam_lastlog.so` module, which shows exactly what you want:

```
session optional pam_lastlog.so noterm nohost
```

Or a bit more verbose:

```
session optional pam_lastlog.so
```

Or one that also prints failed logins:

```
session optional pam_lastlog.so showfailed
```

On Fedora, it might go to `/etc/pam.d/system-login` or `/etc/pam.d/gdm-password`, I'm not sure.

The information is stored in `/var/log/wtmp` and `/var/log/lastlog`.

Comment: Yes it has been showing it like that, but I have a custom MOTD script that scrolls it up out of sight. So I need to be able to output it from the end of my script. Good answer though. I just didn't explain my problem well enough.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe: Change the motd script to be displayed by `pam_motd.so` instead? If it must be different for every user, re-generate it with `pam_exec.so`. Put them above `pam_lastlog.so` in the "session" section.

Comment: Hmmmm. Not sure what you mean/how to do it.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe: Why is the motd displayed by a script? Does it change with time, or does it change for different users?

Comment: It is a colored, somewhat animated, script that changes per user and also changes as time goes by.